# Nginx redirect from domain.com/?go=all/postname/ url to domain.com/blog/postname url

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm Nginx newbie and I'm stuck with redirection problem.

I have a bunch links like this:
http://domain.ru/?go=all/spotify-black-screen/

and i need to make a permanent redirect for it to a links like this:

http://domain.ru/blog/spotify-black-screen/

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot for a help in advance!

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more specific. Which part is varying and how many query strings do you have?

Comment: Thanks for answer, Keenan! I would love to change "?go=all/spotify-black-screen/" to "blog/spotify-black-screen", the "spotify-black-screen" part will be the same in both cases. Would love to make a lot of redirects by the same logic, i'm transfering my blog to other engine. Enough info now?

Comment: Sure, I'll give it a go. Could you post the relevant nginx config? i.e The part with the server and location bits.

Comment: No relevant part at the moment, can't do a redirect at all : (

Comment: It's okay, just need to see the config file. Unless your server isn't up yet?

Comment: Here you go: http://pastebin.com/0PSzpr1M

Comment: Mainly the problem for me is in getting the post name from url without that '?go=all' part and pass it forward.

Comment: You're so nearly there... Add this to the `if ($query_string ~ "go=all(.*)")` `return 301 http://xyz.ru/blog$1` You've captured everything after _all_ and can use it as a back-reference. Since this includes the **/**, don't put a **/** after **blog**

Comment: Keenan, it works perfectly! Glad you helped me make this final step! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad! Do you mind if I edit your original post to include extracts of your NGINX config? I'd like to make this an answer so that others will know that there was a solution.

Comment: Of course! You're welcome